# Keep getting this error on Composer require

Tags: drupal, installation, composer

I'm using the current instructions to get the current version of CiviCRM for Drupal 8

```
[play@ceres web]$ composer require civicrm/civicrm-{core,packages,drupal-8}:'~5.35'
```

It keeps giving me this error

```
- The requested package civicrm/civicrm-core ~5.35 is satisfiable by civicrm/civicrm-core[5.35.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

I'm then trying

```
composer require civicrm/civicrm-{core,packages,drupal-8}:'~5.34.0’
```

and it just hangs.

Any ideas?

Comment: Im now getting the message 'killed' and it's running through 1gb memory, which can't be right.....

Answer (score 1):

The memory problem is real - composer does that. You always need to `export COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1`.

For the conflict, is this drupal 9.1? You can try adding `"minimum-stability": "dev"` to composer.json.

Comment: OK I added the -W parameter to the composer thus

composer -W require civicrm/civicrm-{core,packages,drupal-8}:'~5.34.0’ then it worked

Comment: Cool. There always seems to be some trial and error with composer and it's different in each environment.

Comment: Also I noticed I had an incorrect comma at the end which was breaking everything. Sigh.